# Avoid URL parameter using GET method when clicked on back arrow in browser

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I've got a parameter which indicates if it is the 1st time user have logged in and if it is:

```
mounted: function() {
    if(this.$route.query.welcome == 'true') {
        $('#welcome_dialog').modal();
    }
}
```

a modal shows up which has few steps with some introduction and explanation text. On the last step, there is a button which, when clicked, redirects user to another webpage. The problem I've got is, once the user finds himself on the redirected page, if he decides to click on the back arrow in browser, the URL still has the `welcome` parameter which means that user will have to go all over the same procedure with the `#welcome_dialog` again.

My question is, is there a way to remove this parameter from URL if back arrow is click, or just is there any other way not to show dialog this time? You don't have to post code if you don't want, I am more looking for an idea on how to do this.

**P.S.**

Opening webpage in new tab is not an option.

Comment: in your welcome function store a `done-it` somewhere, cookie or local storage, and check that as well before showing the dialog

Comment: If you really want to do it as you've described, you can use the Javascript [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_replaceState()_method) function to edit the browser history. But as others have suggested, using cookies/LocalStorage is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm gonna try the cookie way

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `welcome` value in local storage or cookie and then read it every time you load that page.

Comment: This should be on comment.

Comment: @WebArtisan I can't comment because "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

Comment: @PiotrLewandowski I'm not going to weigh in on wether or not what you wrote qualifies as an "Answer" or not. However, for future reference, the fact that you do not have enough rep to post a comment does _not_ justify abusing the Answer feature to post what would otherwise be a Comment. Please keep this in mind as it may lead to you getting downvotes, which will just make it harder for you to actually be able to post Comments.

Comment: @PatrickQ you're right, I should have know that. Sorry, I'll remember from now on. Thanks.